# Official PHP:Apache Docker Image - Getting MySql Plugins to Work

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am using the official docker php:apache image but I can't use mysqli with php. 
I get 'Class "mysqli" not found' whenever I try this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

I see a ton of stuff everywhere talking about adding an install for mysqli to the dockerfile.
I am really not sure if this is necessary for a few reasons:

When I open bash on my container, I see that mysqlnd is installed as a php module.

Here's the snippet from my docker-compose.yml:

```
lamp-www:
  depends_on:
  - db
  image: php:apache
  volumes:
  - "./www:/var/www/html"
  ports:
  - 8080:80
```

When I do a PhpInfo(), I see "--enable-mysqlnd" and I see a mysqlnd section. 
It states version name: "mysqlnd 8.0.10".

I haven't seen anything indicating that the syntax is different between the old mysqli and mysqlnd, it suggests it's the same. I've tried using "mysqlnd" and "mysql" instead, but they all generate the same error as "mysqli".

I also am not seeing anything that indicates you can use a DockerFile when using "image: php:apache". I also don't want to go into my container to install or change things, and re-commit, I'd like use the official image.

Can I make a DockerFile when I use the "image" parameter in my docker-compose.yml?
Is there a cleaner way to do this, like just adding a parameter to my compose that installs whatever mysterious thing I'm missing?

Final question: This is the official php image, and the installed modules seem to indicate that  mysql is supported from php. Am I just trying to use functions/classes that aren't recommended? If so, what should I be using instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.overview.php), it says:

> What it is not
>
> Although MySQL Native Driver is written as a PHP extension, it is
> important to note that it does not provide a new API to the PHP
> programmer. The programmer APIs for MySQL database connectivity are
> provided by the MySQL extension, mysqli and PDO MYSQL. These
> extensions can now use the services of MySQL Native Driver to
> communicate with the MySQL Server. Therefore, you should not think of
> MySQL Native Driver as an API.

Basically, `mysqlnd` is in a layer below `mysqli` or `pdo_mysql`, it does not add functions/classes in PHP for you to connect to a MySql db.

This can be checked running a few commands (I'm assuming a flavor of Linux or WSL):

```
docker pull php:apache                 #downloading the official image
docker run --rm -it php:apache bash    #and running it in a temporal container
```

once inside the container:

```
php -m     #checking the modules for php
php -a     #executing a php interactive console
```

(note that in the output of `php -m`, `mysqlnd` is present but `mysqli` or `pdo_mysql` are not)
then, run these lines inside the php console:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'db');              //connecting to a MySql db with mysqli
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'pass'); //and the same with pdo_mysql
```

Both lines will throw an error:

```
Warning: Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found in php shell code:1     //mysqli
Warning: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in php shell code:1 //pdo_mysql
```

Even in standard installations of php in the wild, neither mysqli nor pdo_mysql are bundled by default, because you may want to use other databases (PostgreSQL, SQLite, Oracle, etc...) or none at all, so you need to install the specific driver for your db.

### Installing a MySQL driver with a Dockerfile

Q: Which one should you use, mysqli or pdo_mysql?

A: Nope, i'm not touching this one, go with the one **you** personally feel most comfortable with. This question is on par with "tabs or spaces?", "vi, vim or emacs?", "pineapple on pizza?", "Were Ross and Rachel on a break?" or "Was The Dress blue and black or white and gold?" in terms of divisiveness, both have their pros and cons, and there are no wrong answers <sup><sup><sup>(unless you put pineapple on a pizza, seriously, what's is wrong with you?)</sup></sup></sup>.

To install any, or both drivers you need to create a Dockerfile that creates a new image with php and the drivers ready to use. You don't need to start from scratch or go into the container everytime you run it, since you can base your image on the official one and extend it.

There are instructions to do so in the [readme](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) of the official image, where they mention the helper commands inside the image, but i already did the legwork:

```
#this uses the official image as a starting point
FROM php:apache

#humblebrag
MAINTAINER gorchestopher-h

#install both modules from source, you can delete the one you aren't using
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql
```

that's it! now you have a Dockerfile that you need to save in a file with the name `Dockerfile` (no extension) preferably in a directory right next to your `docker-compose.yml` file, please.

Now that you have this file, you could execute the `docker build` command and create it, but since you're using docker-compose, you're already a few steps ahead with automatization, so you only need to edit your compose file and the first time you run `docker-compose up` with the new configuration it will do the job for you.

But here's the catch, the way the [`image`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#image) key works is:

> If the image does not exist, Compose attempts to pull it, unless you
> have also specified [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build), in which case it builds it using the
> specified options and tags it with the specified tag.

So, that means we can set the `build` key inside the the compose file to build our Dockerfile. ***But!*** it needs to have an unique name so it doesn't get confused with the already existing `php:apache` image in your system and the official repository.

This can be done using both image and build keys:

```
lamp-www:
  depends_on:
      - db 
  image: gorchestopher-h/php-mysql:apache           #the resulting image gets named this
  build: ./name-of-the-directory-next-to-the-yml    #where to find the Dockerfile file
  volumes:
      - "./www:/var/www/html"
  ports:
      - 8080:80
```

And that's it, now the first time you `docker-compose up` this compose file, the image gets built since it can't be found, and if you modify the `Dockerfile` and spin it up again. It does nothing since the image already exists, you need to execute `docker-compose build lamp-www` (the name of the service is optional, if you skip it, it builds every `build` key) to recreate it, and also `docker image prune` after you spin up the new image to free the unused old one.

To check that everything went well, you can repeat the commands from before.

```
docker run --rm -it gorchestopher-h/php-mysql:apache bash #run the container with the awesome new name
```

inside the container you can run

```
php -m #check the installed modules, it should have mysqli and/or pdo_mysql
php -a #executes a php terminal
```

and on the php terminal you can test the connection again

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'db');              //connecting to a MySql db with mysqli
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'pass'); //and the same with pdo_mysql
```

Comment: Wow, incredibly thorough,. Never expected an answer like this! Of course making a dockerfile worked per your recommendation.. It's too bad there's no way to just add an argument to a know image right in the compose yml. The whole build/up process took a few tries, but I eventually got it!

Comment: It can be done (with `entrypoint` and bash shenanigans), but for this specific scenario imagine having to wait everytime you `docker-compose up` for the entire duration of the install process. Is better this way where you create a "state layer" on top of the base image so you don't have to start over everything again.

Comment: Yes, when you put it that way I agree! I was waiting to accept until you get some upvotes out of this, because it's the best explanation of all the components to this I've ever seen, but I might as well accept now.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this since what I have is a dev/home-lab enviroment with 2 x86 manager servers and 4 x raspberry pi workers and I want to update the php:apache image as soon as there is a new one available instead of creating a new image with mysqli or pdo_mysql extension every time there is an update; so I added the entrypoint in my docker-compose as `entrypoint: sh -c "docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli && apache2-foreground"` and it works, it definetly takes a minute or two to come back online after a restart but it works. I have it as a service running as global on all of my nodes; here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  main:
    deploy:
      mode: global # global sevice running on all nodes
    image: php:apache
    entrypoint: sh -c "docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli && apache2-foreground" # In order to enable MySQLi extension
    hostname: 'php_{{.Node.Hostname}}' # Dynamic Hostname assignment for the node
    networks:
      - proxy
    #ports:
    #  - "80:80" # Port not needed since it is reverse proxied 
    volumes:
      - /mnt/nas/dev/index.php:/var/www/html/index.php # mapping only the index.php file (info.php) since it is a test server

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

That way I can point the volume(s) to a specific file(s) or to a root directory and have a dev enviroment on all of my nodes shared on my NAS. I am also using a reverse proxy for this docker, so no need to expose the port.

**EDIT:**
Since I noticed that uninitialized nodes were receiving requests, I implemented a 'health check' to ensure that only nodes that have completed the mysqli extension installation respond to requests:

```
    healthcheck:
      test: "curl --fail http://localhost || exit 1"
      interval: 30s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
      timeout: 10s
```